# Who provides CA SSL certificate in case of Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

We have an entry in Route 53 table in AWS. Let's say, `aliasUrl` for which we have the destination URL as `destUrl`. Now, when a client tries to ping the `aliasUrl`, it gets resolved to the `destUrl`. Now, I want to know which of these two Urls shares the SSL certificate when a request is made by a client to the `aliasUrl` ?